# add onClickListener to navigation view header using android design support library

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

I want to add a onClickListener to navigation view header's items like changing a TextView text or set an image for ImageView.

Comment: This question might benefit from some code e.g. show what you have tried so far.

Comment: i haven't tried any code for this part,i want some thing  like what gmail app do in navigation view header.

Comment: People won't give code like that. Try first yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your activity_main.xml layout add navigation drawer code.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"></FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and adder your drawer_header.xml in the layout directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My header"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
```

add nav_menu.xml to your menu directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/main_features"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/idHome"
        android:title="Home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:title="Favorites" />


   <item
        android:id="@+id/idSettings"
        android:title="Settings" />


</group>
```

in your MainActivity.java listen to the clicks

```
 DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
 NavigationView mNavigationView;
 TextView header;
```

then initialize them in your onCreate():

```
 mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
 mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
  header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Calling Header", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Update:  27/10/2015

with the update on support library adding header to the navigation view in xml is not working, may be its a bug.

to add a header view 
inflate the view as  navigation view header in java.

```
mNavigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.layout_header_profile);
```

hope it will help. 
Happy Coding...

Comment: thanks i aleady added the navigation view,i just want handler for header,thannks any way

Comment: Beware that from support appcompat library v23.1 the way to get the headerView reference is to call `navigationView.getHeaderView(0)` (if you have only one header)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this -

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

or if you have multiple headers:

```
navigationView.getHeaderCount();
```

[Reference](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190226#c31)

Answer (score 1):

Set onClickListener in XML on your view like so:

```
android:onClick="onLabelClick"
```

Then in your activity

```
public void onLabelClick(View view) {
    // do stuff :)
}
```